# How do you utilize $and, $or, $exists in the same Mongoose.js query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to query documents for an account that either has no expiration[expires] (does not exist) or the expiration date is after 2/2/14.  To do so, my mongodb query is:

```
db.events.find({ _account: ObjectId("XXXX"), 
    $or: [
        {expires: {$gt: ISODate('2014-02-02')}}, 
        {expires: {$exists: false}}
    ]
});
```

I'm having trouble with the correct mongoose `.or()` `.and()` `.exists()` chaining, how would I convert this into Mongoose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There should be nothing wrong with using the same syntax, more or less as in the shell. It's still javascript, just without the shell helpers.

```
Events.find({ _account: "XXXX", 
  $or: [
    {expires: {$gt: Date(2014,02,02)}},
    {expires: {$exists: false }}
}, function(err, events) {
    if (err) // TODO
    // do something with events
});
```

Alternately you are using other helpers to build the query:

```
var query = Events.find({ _account: "XXXX" });

query.or(
    {expires: {$gt: Date(2014,02,02)}},
    {expires: {$exists: false }}
);

query.exec(function(err, events) { 
   if (err) // TODO
   // do something with events
});
```

Or other combinations. These 'helpers' largely exist in drivers for syntax parity with other non-dynamic languages like Java. You can look for examples of [QueryBuilder](https://www.google.com/search?q=mongodb%20java%20querybuilder) usage in Java if you prefer this way and can't find the node references. For mongoose there is the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) for queries that is worth a look.

Dynamic languages have a more native approach to defining such object structures as used for queries etc. So most people prefer to use them.

Comment: ah, fantastic- I thought I had to use the helpers and wasn't sure how the "or" was implemented in conjunction with the original "find".  I will try this when back in the office later today.